# Regex in javascript to remove "

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all occurence of " from the String in javascript

Comment: Please check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` with `regex`. This will remove all the `"` in `str` string.

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, '');
```

`g`(**global**) flag will make the `regex` to `replace` all occurrences of `"` in `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/"/g, "");
```